# В C++ выдаёт ошибку даже при запуске первой программы - Hello, World!

Tags: c++, codeblocks

Только-только решил работать с **С++**, раньше работал с **Python**. Нашёл на платформе Сириус.Курсов курс про этот язык, делал всё как там говорили. Установил **Code::Blocks** с оригинального сайта, всё нормально было, написал программу ***Hello, World!***, запустил и тут же компьютер выдал ошибку. Подскажите, пожалуйста в чём заключается моя ошибка. Вот код программы:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout<<"Hello, World! << endl;"; 
    return 0;
}
```

Вот ошибка:

```
Project/Target: "CPp - Debug":
  The compiler's setup (GNU GCC Compiler) is invalid, so Code::Blocks cannot find/run the compiler.
  Probably the toolchain path within the compiler options is not setup correctly?!
  Do you have a compiler installed?
Goto "Settings->Compiler...->Global compiler settings->GNU GCC Compiler->Toolchain executables" and fix the compiler's setup.

Tried to run compiler executable 'C:\MinGW/bin/mingw32-gcc.exe', but failed!

Skipping...
Nothing to be done (all items are up-to-date).
```

Comment: Ну он же ясно пишет, что не настроен компилятор, и что надо зайти в настройки `Settings->Compiler...->Global compiler settings->GNU GCC Compiler->Toolchain executables` и исправить ошибки.

Comment: Спасибо, попробую. Когда в переводчик забиваю, пишем что попало.

Comment: Вы, надеюсь, установили CodeBlocks *вместе с компилятором*? Сам CodeBlocks — просто среда разработки, компилятор идет отдельно (или в пакете с ним, но надо выбрать верный пакет).

Comment: Поставь вижуал. Он тебе ошибки на русском будет выдавать. А кодеблокс для про только.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас или не установлен, или неверно выбран компилятор. При выборе указанного пункта меню откроется диалоговое окно настроек, в нем надо правилдьно указать, где находится ваш компилятор (если он установлен). Если не установлен - его надо установить, а затем указать в Code::Blocks, где именно он установлен.

Comment: Небольшая поправка: если вдруг установлен компилятор mingw-w64, то C::B его не найдет, т.к. в нем по умолчанию "забиты" другие (из комплекта mingw или TDM-mingw) имена исполняемых файлов. В смысле, нужно еще переименовать имена на просто `gcc` и `g++` для компиляторов и линкера.

Comment: @Vladimir Спасибо за дополнение!

Comment: Понятно, спасибо