# Couldn't create the project directory: Ошибка в CodeBlocks

Tags: c, codeblocks

При попытке создать проект мне выдает ошибку **Couldn't create the project directory**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я создал отдельную папку для проектов "gg" в самой директории программы CodeBlocks
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Может, прав не хватает — в `Program Files` писать?...

Comment: Попробуйте в другой какой-то каталог писать. Писать в каталог `C:\Program Files` и его подкаталоги нехорошо, мягко говоря. Туда по-хорошему только система должна писать, сами проги туда тоже ничего не пишут. Система защищает код программ от изменения и каталоги, где он лежит, и это правильно.

Comment: @CrazyElf Спасибо за ответ, мне помогло!

Comment: @CrazyElf Но теперь у меня ошибка **Tried to run compiler executable *C:\Program Files\CodeBlocks\MinGW/bin/gcc.exe' but failed**

Comment: Это уже второй вопрос, как говорится. Что-то у вас неправильно настроено. Почитайте тут например https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1344988/%D0%92-c-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%91%D1%82-%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D1%83-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D1%8B-hello-world

Answer (score 0):

Вам не следует ничего писать в каталог `C:\Program Files` и его подкаталоги. Операционная система заботится о том, чтобы код программ никто случайно не испортил или не подменил и обычно запрещает писать в такие каталоги всем, кроме самой системы и администратора. Можно, конечно, дать себе права на запись в этот каталог, но это потенциально не безопасно. Лучше всё же создать специальный каталог для своих работ: либо что-то типа `C:\Work`, либо в какой-то папке конкретного пользователя, например `C:\Users\тут_ваше_имя_пользователя\Documents\`